# Keep equal gaps between CSS multi-column items

Tags: css, css-multicolumn-layout

I want the left-most and right-most margins of my columns to be the same as the space in between them. I think [my codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXrpmp?editors=110) demonstrates it pretty well. Just in case that isn't clear,
[image: the image]

I'd like the red gaps labeled in red to all be the same, as opposed to how they currently are.

Here's the code I'm basing this off of:

```
.columns {
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-rule: solid 1px #000;
  -moz-column-rule: solid 1px #000;
  column-rule: solid 1px #000;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #f00;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: De the `.item`s that you want to display in your columns have a fixed width?

Comment: Yep. It doesn't matter though, I'm just going to move to Masonry.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this

```
.item {
display: inline-block;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-color: #f00;
margin-bottom: 20px;
margin-left Xpx; //Add this
margin-right Xpx;//Add this ,X is your desired value
}
```

Comment: It depends on relative to which you wanted to align columns. I assuming you are not going for responsive design. So you  can make column div of certain size and you can divide into sections you mentioned above. So u can get x value from 6X+3*200= Total Div Width. Anyway  this is not the best case

Comment: Sorry but I don't think you actually looked at my code. CSS 3 multi-columns are fluid.